# MPI comunication between C++ and Fortran

Tags: c++, fortran, mpi

I have a simple question: do I need a special method for communicating between a C program and a Fortran program via MPI? To be specific, the C program is the `parent`, and the Fortran program is the `child` which is spawned using `MPI_Comm_spawn`. Naturally, each process (the `parent` and `child`) can populate an inter-communicator handle to perform `MPI_Send` and `MPI_Recv` between the `parent` and `child`. But for some reason, I get `MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL` `MPI_ERR_TYPE: invalid datatype`. I am wondering if there is a compatibility issue between C and Fortran, and that if I need some special consideration.

Edit: I am sending an array of characters. So the code of interest would look something like this:

```
// C++ code

// standard MPI initialization stuff.

MPI_Comm_spawn("path/to/fortran/code", MPI_ARGV_NULL, 1, MPI_INFO_NULL, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &children, MPI_ERRCODES_IGNORE)
char file_name[]  = "/../../foo.inp"; // char array of length 56 including null character
MPI_Send(file_name, 56, MPI_CHAR, dest, tag, children);
```

```
! Fortran code

! Standard MPI initializations

character(len=100) :: file_name
call mpi_recv(file_name, 56, MPI_CHARACTER, src, tag, parent, ...)
```

To run the program, I would do:

```
>> mpirun -np 1 ./cpp_code
```

Thanks

Comment: Please show the actual code ([mcve]). Do you use any custom MPI datatypes? If you really just want to ask in general and not debug your current problem then the answer is no. You do not need anything special but make sure that the datatypes describe the data correctly. If youbwhat to know why you have the error, the code is needed.

Comment: Also, you are writing about C, but you are using the C++ tag. These are different languages. Do you use the C API in C++?

Comment: you are sending 56 `MPI_CHAR` but `file_name` does not contain that many. That being said, the error does not seem related to that issue. please post a [mcve] using MPMD to keep it simple (e.g. `mpirun -np 1 ./c_program : -np 1 ./fortran_program`)

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Hi all, thanks for your comments. I have made some revisions to my question. Please take a look.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава

Comment: Well that's not code enough to tell much, if you really do want an answer please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as requested by both Vladimir and Gilles already. But just to check the obvious, you do have the appropriate header files/modules in scope?

Comment: Make sure you have `implicit none` in Fortran. But please really post a *reproducible* code, that means that others may attempt to reproduce the error. I agree with Gilles that MPMD (multiple programs) is easier than spawning.

Comment: A third vote for the avoidance of spawning.

Comment: Last but not least, which MPI library (vendor and version) are you using?